# Click on a link and go to a input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to make a link to a input. My current link example works (takes me to the area where the id is set) but what I really want is when a user clicks on the link to take him exactly to the input, being able to type right away.

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search">

<a href="#search">
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/something.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Is this even achievable without JQuery/JavaScript? Please post solutions in any method you can imagine. Been searching for this for a while and couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No need to use javascript: use a `label` instead of a link with the `for` attribute

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search">

<label for="search">
   <img src="http://www.example.com/images/something.jpg" alt="something">
</label>
```

---

if you also need a smooth page scroll animation, in order to reach the top offset of the input element, you can instead use a script, e.g.

Codepen Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLyOqg

```
$(function() {
   $('label[for]').on('click', function(evt) {

      evt.preventDefault();
      var inputId = "#" + $(this).attr('for');

      $('html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)').animate({
          scrollTop: $(inputId).offset().top
      }, 600, function() {
          $(inputId).focus();
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
function setFocus(){
    elm = document.getElementById("search");
    jump(elm);
    elm.focus();
}

function jump(elm){
    var top = elm.offsetTop; //Getting Y of target element
    window.scrollTo(0, top);                        //Go there.
}​
</script>
```

...

```
<a href="javascript:setFocus('search')">
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/something.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery focus!

```js
$('[href="#search"]').click(function(){$('#search').focus();});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" name="search">

<a href="#search">
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/something.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```